# Bash Scripts Are Not Executing From Production Build of Electron App

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, electron, electron-builder

**UPDATE**: index.js file content added.
I have this electron app that is executing some bash scrips(***.sh**) files to perform some task.
Everything is working absolutely fine in the development environment but when building the production build for `deb` installer for **Ubuntu platform**, everything is working, like opening on the app, other NodeJS stuff, but bash scripts are not executing.

**Problem Statement**: How to execute shell scripts in the production build of an electron app for Linux(Ubuntu OS). Getting this error

> app/terminal_scripts/timer.sh Not Found

Below are the detailed explanation for the app.

**Project Directory Setup**:
    ProjectName
     |
      app > css | images | js | renders 
      terminal_scripts 
      node_modules
      package.json
      package-lock.json

Where inside the app directory, I have all CSS, images, js, HTML, and terminal scripts.

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "timer",
  "productName": "Timely",
  "version": "1.0.25",
  "description": "This desktop app shows you system clock",
  "main": "app/js/main/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "nodemon --exec 'electron .'",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "homepage": ".",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "Desktop App"
  ],
  "author": "NotABot Ltd <contact@notabot.com>",
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Not A Bot",
      "email": "nab@notabot.com"
    }
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "desandro-matches-selector": "^2.0.2",
    "electron-context-menu": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-is": "^3.0.0",
    "fix-path": "^3.0.0",
    "isotope-layout": "^3.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "jquery-bridget": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.test.timely",
    "productName": "Timely",
    "linux": {
      "target": "deb",
      "category": "System"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.1.1", 
    "electron-builder": "^22.6.0"
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Timely</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="displayTime()">Display Time</button>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="90" id="command-output" disabled="true"></textarea>
   
    <script>
        const {app} = require('electron');
        function displayTime(){
            console.log("button clicked");
            let cmd = `bash app/terminal_scripts/timer.sh`;
            
            let completeMessage = 'This is the message';
            backgroundProcess(cmd, completeMessage);
        }

        function getCommandOutput() { return document.getElementById("command-output");  };
        function getStatus()      { return document.getElementById("status");  };


        function appendOutput(msg) { getCommandOutput().value += (msg+'\n'); };
        function setStatus(msg)    { getStatus().innerHTML = msg; };
        
        function backgroundProcess(cmd, completeMessage){
            const process = require('child_process');
            
            var child = process.execFile(cmd, [] , {shell: true} );
            appendOutput("Processing......");
            child.on('error', function(err) {
                appendOutput('stderr: '+err );
            });

            child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                appendOutput(data);
            });

            child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
                appendOutput(data );
            });

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                child.on('close', function (code) {
                    console.log(`code is: ${code}`);
                    if (code == 0){
                        setStatus(completeMessage);
                        resolve(1);  
                    }
                    else{
                        setStatus('Exited with error code ' + code);
                        resolve(-1);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Bash Script**:

```
#!/bin/bash
timer="$(date)"
echo "$timer"
```

> Permission is set 777 for this shell file

**Platform Information**:

1. OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
2. NodeJS: 13.6.0
3. NPM: 6.14.5
4. Electron: 8.1.1
5. Electron Builder: 22.6.0

**index.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, Tray, ipcMain, MenuItem} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const contextMenu = require('electron-context-menu');

let splashWindow;


function createMainWindow(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        minHeight: 700,
        minWidth: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            webviewTag: true
        },
        show: false
    });
    //For dev only
    // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.loadFile('app/renderer/index.html');
    mainWindow.maximize();
}
app.on('ready', () =>{
    createMainWindow();
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can paste a sample of `app/js/main/index.js` which is in you package.json.

Comment: @Philippe I have added index.js file, you can have a look, but I don't think this file is linked with the execution of the shell scripts.

Comment: Are you sure `app/terminal_scripts/timer.sh` is included in production build ? How did you make production build ?

Comment: @Philippe Using electron-build. As you can see in my index.html files I am executing the shell files using ``process.execFile`` but in production build it is showing app/terminal_scripts_timer.sh is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new directory alongside the `app` directory called the `termainal_scripts`.

Inside this, I have my bash file **timer.sh**.

I figured out how to execute shell scripts, in production by using `process.resourcesPath` inside `path.join()`.

So, let the fixed path be as:

`let fixedURL = path.join(process.resourcesPath, '/terminal_scripts/');`

Then the command to execute will be:

`` let cmd = `${fixedURL}timer.sh` ``

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to move flies to a new directory outside  `app` directory and call it as `extraResources`.

Inside that directory you can add all your bash files and for production you can use below method.

`let urlPath = path.join(process.resourcesPath, '/extraResources/')`

and then use `` let cmd = `${urlPath}timer.sh` ``;